# What minimum angular speed required for coin to spin on table?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, estimation, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

When a coin is spinning on the table around the vertical axis passing its center, what is the minimum angular speed ($\omega$) is required to maintain this spinning?

I would be thankful if you help me with this problem.

Comment: Assuming there is no friction I guess any $\omega>0$ will do. Though I'm probably wrong so... ideas?